Could not create message from InputStream: Invalid Content-Type:application/xml
I created a soap API at endpoint:localhost:8082/ws  and when I text it on Postman I get this error:

Error occurred during jwt authentication: Request processing failed: org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Invalid Content-Type:application/xml.

Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
This is my request:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                  xmlns:ns="http://example.com/accounts">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:GetAccountRequest>
         <ns:accountId>2</ns:accountId>
      </ns:GetAccountRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

This is my code:
@Endpoint
public class AccountEndpoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://example.com/accounts";

    private final AccountService accountService;

    public AccountEndpoint(AccountService accountService) {
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "GetAccountRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetAccountResponse getAccount(@RequestPayload GetAccountRequest request) {
        return accountService.getAccount(request);
    }
}

@Service
public class AccountService {
    
    @Autowired
    private AccountLicenseRepository accountLicenseRepository;

    public GetAccountResponse getAccount(GetAccountRequest request) {
        GetAccountResponse response = new GetAccountResponse();
        
        AccountLicenseEntity accountLicenseEntity = accountLicenseRepository.findById(request.getAccountId()).get();
        
        response.setFirstName(accountLicenseEntity.getFirstName());
        response.setLastName(accountLicenseEntity.getLastName());
        
        return response;
    }
}

Please solve my problem for this API.
